# Is there an elementary proof of Fourier's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, alternative-proof

## Fourier's Theorem

An arbitrary periodic function $F(t)$ with period $T$ can be decomposed into a linear combination of the functions $f_n(t)$ and $g_n(t)$ where,
$$f_n(t)=\sin \frac {2πnt}{T}$$
$$g_n(t)=\cos \frac {2πnt}{T}$$
Mathematically,
$$F(t)=b_0 + b_1g_1(t) +b_2g_2(t) + …… + a_1f_1(t) +a_2f_2(t) + ……,$$
where $n$ is a non-negative integer and all of $a_i$,$b_i$ are real.

## Problem

As $F(t)$ is periodic with period $T$ ,
$$F(t+nT)=F(t)…….… (1)$$.
What I want is that I can derive the RHS directly from equation (1). However, I am unable to do so, perhaps in lack of theoretical knowledge. Any suggestions are welcome.

## Note

What ever proofs I have got as yet, they assume the decomposition for some complex exponential and justify it using some arguments. I don't want anything like that

Comment: It is not true that *any* periodic function can be written in the way you claim. At the very least, the function needs to be measurable. Also, it is not true that $\int_0^T f(t) \, dt =0$ if $f$ is T-periodic.

Comment: @PhoemueX, sorry , I was quite biased to write the integral. As for now , I have correct it.

Comment: Do you know the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) ? The Fourier series is $\lim_{N \to \infty} F \ast D_N$ where $\ast$ is the (periodic) convolution. Then we show that $D_N(t) \approx N h(Nt)$ and under some conditions $\lim_{N \to \infty} F \ast D_N =\lim_{N \to \infty}  F \ast N h(Nt) = F$. The alternative is to show that $\{ e^{2i \pi n t}\}$ is an orthonormal family of $L^2([0,1])$ and that it is dense so it is an orthonormal basis and $F = \sum_n \langle F,e^{2i \pi n t}\rangle e^{2i \pi n t}$

Comment: @reuns, where does the Dirichlet kernel itself come from? In case you can answer this very question , the proof is complete.